# Python - loop through file to call most recent row that contained a variable in current row

Tags: python, loops, csv, call

I'm trying to improve my Python skills and general basic coding. I have a csv file, the first 7 rows (including the header) of which are shown below:

```
HomeTeam     AwayTeam      HomeTeamWin     AwayTeamWin
AV           MU            1               0
BR           QPR           1               0
C            E             0               1
MU           BR            1               0
QPR          C             0               1
E            AV            0               1
```

I am trying to implement the following code such that an output file will be generated that shows, based on the result from their most recent game, if the home team was / was not coming off a win. I am stuck at the section marked with ******

```
#start loop
for row in file:
    #create empty list to put value we will find into
    observation_list=[]
    #define variable a as being row[0], i.e. the cell 
    #in the current row that contains the 'hometeam'
    a=row[0]
    #*****stuck here*******#
    #call the last row to contain variable a i.e. where toprow = the most recent row
    #above the current row to have contained varaible a i.e. the value from row[0]
    for toprow in file:
    #*****stuck here*******#
        if (toprow[0] or toprow[1])==a: 
            #implement the following if statement
            #where toprow[0] is the 1st column containing the value
            #of the hometeam from the toprow
            if (toprow[0]==a):      
            #implement the following to generate an output file showing
            #1 or 0 for home team coming off a win
                b=toprow[2]
                observation_list.append(b)
                with open(Output_file, "ab") as resultFile:
                     writer = csv.writer(resultFile, lineterminator='\n')
                     writer.writerow(observation_list)  
            else (toprow[1]==a):
            #implement the following if statement
            #where toprow[1] is the 1st column containing the value
            #of the hometeam from the toprow
                b==toprow[3]
                observation_list.append(b])
            #implement the following to generate an output file showing
            #1 or 0 for home team coming off a win
                with open(Output_file, "ab") as resultFile:
                     writer = csv.writer(resultFile, lineterminator='\n')
                     writer.writerow(observation_list)
```

From what I have done and read thus far I can see there being two problems:

Problem 1: how can I get the second for loop, marked with ****, to iterate over the previously read rows until it reaches the most recent row to contain the variable define by 'a' ?

Problem 2: How do I start the code block from the 3rd row? The reason this needs to be done is to prevent A. reading the header and, more importantly, B. trying to read a non existent / negative row i.e. row1 - 1 = row0, row0 doesn't exist!?

NB the desired output file would be as follows:

```
-blank-      #first cell would be empty as there is no data to fill it
-blank-      #second cell would be empty as there is no data to fill it
-blank-      #third cell would be empty as there is no data to fill it
0            #fourth cell contains 0 as MU lost their most recent game
0            #fifth cell contains 0 as QPR lost their most recent game
1            #sixth cell contains 1 as E won their most recent game
```

Comment: Im on mobile so can't write a full answer, but google memorization and see if it helps

Comment: early in the loop, ```a==row[0]``` is a comparison - did you intend that to be an assignment?

Comment: Problem1: Read all the lines of the file into a data structure, container, that you can iterate over.  You may want to thnk a bit about your problem and imagine the best way to *store* each line.  Problem2: You can skip lines in a file-object with ```file.next()```.

Comment: @wii, I have edited the comparison out and replaced it with a=row[0]. Ditto for variable b.     Re the storing I believe that is the nexus of the problem, I just can't see or find the solution.

Comment: @Nick Bailey, I'm reading into memoization as I think there could be a solution there, it's quite intense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good thing to do is to write down, in words, the steps you think you need to take to solve the problem.  For this problem I want to:

1. skip the first line of the file
2. read a line, and split it into its parts
3. If this is the home team's first game print a blank, if not print the result of the last game it played.
4. repeat till the file is exhausted.

While the file is being read, store the result of the most recently played game so it can be looked up later.  [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) are made for this - `{team1 : result_of_last_game, team2 : result_of_last_game, ...}`.  When looking up each team's first game, there wont be a previous game - the dictionary will *throw* a `KeyError`.  the `KeyError` can be [handled](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) with a `try/except` block or [`collections.defaultdictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be used to account for this.

I like to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) when extracting items from a sequence - it makes the code a bit more readable for when I look at it later.

```
import operator, collections

home = operator.itemgetter(0,2)    #first and third item
away = operator.itemgetter(1,3)    #second and fourth item
team = operator.itemgetter(0)      #first item

#dictionary to hold the previous game's result
#default will be a blank string
last_game = collections.defaultdict(str)

#string to format the output
out = '{}\t{}'
with open('data.txt') as f:
    #skip the header
    f.next()
    #data = map(parse, f)
    for line in f:
        #split the line into its relavent parts
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        #extract the team and game result
        #--> (team1, result), (team2, result)
        h, a = home(line), away(line)
        home_team = team(h)
        #print the result of the last game
        print(out.format(home_team, last_game[home_team]))
        #update the dictionary with the results of this game
        last_game.update([h,a])
```

---

Instead of printing the results, you could easily write them to a file or collect them in a container and write them to a file later.

---

If you want something other than an empty string for your `defaultdict`, you could do something like this

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.__foo = foo
    def __call__(self):
        return self.__foo
blank = Foo('-blank-')
last_game = collections.defaultdict(blank)
```

Comment: thanks for the input. When I run the above code on my test file (circa 50 rows) it throws the following error: line 26, in <module>
    h, a = home(line), away(line)
IndexError: list index out of range    . I'm not sure why it would do this, perhaps because my source file is a csv file?? Re the itemgetter function thank you very much for enlightening me; its a really cool function! I'd be grateful if you've any insights on the error code.....

Comment: @Section_4 one of the lines of your file, when split, doesn't produce enough items.  The ```itemgetters``` are extracting items 0,1,2, and 3.  If the data in your lines are delineated by something other than whitespace, you will need to use that character in the ```split``` function.  If some of your lines have less than four *columns*, you could deal with that by handling the exception with a ```try/except``` block.

Comment: I took you comments on board to great effect. Many thanks for taking the time to read and work through my problem. Without your help I wouldn't have got my code working! Cheers :)